# doors dxl - listing of dead inlinks

Tags: hyperlink, ibm-doors

I like to have dxl script which lets me list out the dead inlinks, i.e list out links leading to a deleted object.

i tried if any option is there in doors but could not find it.

Can you please help in this.

Thanks

Comment: This is a difficult thing to test, since when DOORS is operating properly, it should not let users delete objects that have incoming links. Do you have an example of a situation where an object gets deleted but the link stays behind?

Answer (score 2):

I have been investigating this issue for a long time and I have not been able to identify the cause of this issue and neither has IBM.  Standard practice should be to always delete outlinks before softDeleting objects and make sure not to use the adminisitrative remove lock function while a user has a Module Opened in share edit with a lock on a section while an object modification or link modifications is being made. Doing so will help to eliminate this issue but not entirely since it happens allot and I have not been able to replicate this issue entirely.

The best way to find the Deadlinks is to use targetAbsNo and sourceAbsNo and check the source/target object for that incoming/outgoing matching AbsNo and module. If you try to set the outlink target to an object, DOORS will ignore this object and it will not find the DeadLink I.E(Object targetobj = target(lnk)).

If the objects have not been purged you can still remove the deadlinks by using the link analysis wizzard on the source object, creating a new link to the object with the deadlink and then deleting this link and saving your changes. If the object with deadlinks has been purged your are out of luck, I have not found a way of removing this types of links to and from objects that don't exist.  Also you will want to know the non deleted objects with deadlinks so that this aren't softDeleted/purged and create issues with outlinks to non existent objects.

I did this code out of the back of my head so it has not been tested and it will not work, but you should get an idea of how to look for the DeadLinks. The object() and the Source and Target Module naming is incorrect, I don't remember exactly the syntax used for opening the Target Modules and I don't have access to the documentation at the moment, my apologies.

Copy paste the results into excel and you will get a nice spreadsheet.

```
Object objSrc 
Link lnkTargetLink
Module modMain = read("/Project/YourModule", true, true) 
modMain = current
filtering off
showDeletedObjects true
Buffer bufDeadObjects = create
bufDeadObjects = "Error\tSource Object\tTarget Module\tTarget Object\n"
for objSrc in modMain do {
    for lnkTargetLink in all(objSrc -> "*") do {
         Module targetMod = target module lnkTargetLink //Incorrect syntax
         int intTargetAbs = targetAbsNo lnkTargetLink 
         showDeletedObjects (true)
         filtering off
         Object objTarget = object(intTargetAbs, targetMod) 
         if(null objTarget) {
               bufDeadObjects += "Target Object Does not Exist\t"sourceAbsNo lnkTargetLink "\t" fullName targetMod "\t" intTargetAbs"\n"
         } else {
               Link lnkSourceLink
               bool boolFoundLink = false
               for lnkSourceLink in all(objTarget <- "*") do {
                    if(sourceAbsNo lnkSourceLink != intTargetAbs) continue
                    Module modSourceMod =  source module lnkSourceLink //Incorrect syntax
                    if(fullName modSourceMod != fullName targetMod ) continue
                    boolFoundLink = true
               }
               if(!boolFoundLink and isDeleted(objTarget)) {
                    bufDeadObjects += "DeadInlink on a Deleted Object\t"sourceAbsNo lnkTargetLink "\t" fullName targetMod "\t" intTargetAbs"\n"
               } else if (boolFoundLink and isDeleted(objTarget)){
                    bufDeadObjects += "Outlink to a Deleted Object\t"sourceAbsNo lnkTargetLink "\t" fullName targetMod "\t" intTargetAbs"\n"
               } else {
                    bufDeadObjects += "DeadOutlink\t"sourceAbsNo lnkTargetLink "\t" fullName targetMod "\t" intTargetAbs"\n"
               }
         }
    }
}
print stringOf (bufDeadObjects)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not run the following code, and this isn't optimally efficient, but it will get you started:

```
Link lnk ; for lnk in all obj->"*" do
{
    ModuleVersion targetmv = targetVersion(lnk)
    Module targetmod = load(mv,false)
    Object targetobj = target(lnk)
    if((null targetobj) || (isDeleted targetobj)) { /*dead link*/ }
    close(targetmod)
    delete(targetmv)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Edit > Purge all` will purge/remove all deleted objects including all their dead links!

Observe that un-delete is not possible after this action.

Comment: But that's not useful when there are dead links to non-deleted objects